# Cannot yum install any packages

Tags: yum

No matter what package I am try to install, Yum returns a `[Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory error` for each package/dependency.

Here is some sample output:

```
# yum -y install vim
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirrors.ocf.berkeley.edu
 * extras: mirror.tocici.com
 * updates: mirror.sesp.northwestern.edu
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vim-enhanced.x86_64 2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: vim-common = 2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1 for package: 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libgpm.so.2()(64bit) for package: 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package gpm-libs.x86_64 0:1.20.7-5.el7 will be installed
---> Package vim-common.x86_64 2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: vim-filesystem for package: 2:vim-common-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package vim-filesystem.x86_64 2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution

Dependencies Resolved

==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                                     Arch                                                Version                                                           Repository                                            Size
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Installing:
 vim-enhanced                                                x86_64                                              2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1                                               updates                                              1.0 M
Installing for dependencies:
 gpm-libs                                                    x86_64                                              1.20.7-5.el7                                                      base                                                  32 k
 vim-common                                                  x86_64                                              2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1                                               updates                                              5.9 M
 vim-filesystem                                              x86_64                                              2:7.4.160-1.el7_3.1                                               updates                                              9.7 k

Transaction Summary
==============================================================================================================================================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package (+3 Dependent packages)

Total download size: 7.0 M
Installed size: 23 M
Downloading packages:


Error downloading packages:
  gpm-libs-1.20.7-5.el7.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  2:vim-filesystem-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  2:vim-enhanced-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
  2:vim-common-7.4.160-1.el7_3.1.x86_64: [Errno 5] [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

it looks like it's able to connect to the repository and sees the packages/dependencies needed, but it when it goes to download it fails. I don't know much about managing repos and yum, but this looks like it could be an issue on the local machine?

Distro is CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core) on AWS.

Comment: What does `strace -o lotsalogs -ff -e trace=file yum -y install vim` show happening?

Comment: Try `yum clean all` and then `yum install...` again.

Comment: @Thomas `yum clean all` did not resolve the issue unfortunately.

Comment: @thrig Thanks for that strace command, I'm seeing some issues with finding the python modules.  I was monkeying around with different python installations earlier so this is probably some residual impact from that.

Comment: Yeah you might not want to mess around with the vendor space like that. Use a `virtualenv` or software depot outside of the vendor space...

Comment: was a solution found? I see the same problem and am stuck

Answer (score 2):

On one of the servers I noticed the file `/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down` had this on the top:
`#! /usr/bin/python`
But the python symlink was broken. typing `python --version` would throw an error saying `command not found`
Created a symlink for python pointing to python2.7 and that fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

You should be fine with

`ln -s /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down-2.7 /usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down`

Answer (score 1):

If you read the source code of yum and urlgrabber you will find that:

yum uses python module `urlgrabber` to download rpm packages whose high-level async api `parallel_wait` is associated to an internal class of the package `_ExternalDownloader`.

And the `urlgrabber-ext-down`'s dir is **hard code** written in the class `_ExternalDownloader` as `/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down` in **line 2075** of the `urlgrabber/grabber.py`.

> ```
> def __init__(self):
>     self.popen = subprocess.Popen(
>         '/usr/libexec/urlgrabber-ext-down',
>         stdin = subprocess.PIPE,
>         stdout = subprocess.PIPE,
>     )
>     self.stdin  = self.popen.stdin.fileno()
>     self.stdout = self.popen.stdout.fileno()
>     self.running = {}
>     self.cnt = 0
> ```

So just make sure your `urlgrabber-ext-down` is right there, or rewrite the code **line 2075**.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed the issue for me https://blog.51cto.com/chaichuan/2083574. Basically had to change the python version in the two files mentioned in the link to 2.7